# Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() против isInterrupted() - баг или фича ?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Наследовался от класса thread. 
статью Skipy читал, умные книжки тоже, но это меня удивило:

```
class R extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println("start " + getName() + "  " + isInterrupted());
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

    }
    System.out.println("stop " + getName() + "  " + isInterrupted());
}}
```

тестовый метод:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread th = new Thread(new R());
    th.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    th.interrupt();
    System.out.println("check   " + th.isInterrupted());

}
```

Этот код работает. Но когда я заменяю в классе R проверку Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() на обычный вызов .isInterrupted() он всё время возвращает false и цикл превращается в бесконечность. Почему ? такая разница? это же эквивалентно - вызываю этот метод из дополнительного потока только двумя разными способами.

зы очередной козырь в пользу наследования от Runnable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разница в том, что фактически вы вызываете метод `isInterrupted` двух соверешенно разных экземпляров класса `Thread`.

Вызов `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` обращается к потоку, созданному как `new Thread(new R())`.

Вызов `isInterrupted()` обращается к потоку, созданному как `new R()`.